# Symfony 2 Form: Set field required depending on checkbox not in entity

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a Symfony form mapped to an entity, but there are three optional values. Each of this value has a checkbox associated to it, and those checkboxes are actually not mapped to the entity.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('checkbox1', 'checkbox', array(
            'mapped' => false,
            'label_render' => false,
            'required' => false,
        ))
        ->add('value1', 'text', array(
            'required' => false,
        ))
        ->add('checkbox2', 'checkbox', array(
            'mapped' => false,
            'label_render' => false,
            'required' => false,
        ))
        ->add('value2', 'text', array(
            'required' => false,
        ))
        ->add('checkbox3', 'checkbox', array(
            'mapped' => false,
            'label_render' => false,
            'required' => false,
        ))
        ->add('value3', 'text', array(
            'required' => false,
        ))
    ;
}
```

I'd like to make the text fields required if their respective checkbox is checked. I know about validation callbacks inside the entity, but here the checkbox fields are actually not mapped, so I need something at the form level. I saw something about validation groups callbacks inside the setDefaultOptions method, but all the examples are too tightly related to actual entities. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use a EventListener.

Follow the doc : http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/form_events.html.

You could do something like :

```
->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
     ->add('value1', 'text', array(
        'required' => true,
    ))
})
```

When the checkbox is check. You must do it with Ajax post method. It's pretty simple.